# WordPress on AWS EC2 with Docker-Compose and AWS RDS MySQL Database

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a WordPress website on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 server, in a Docker container using Docker-Compose, and using an AWS RDS MySQL database instead of having the database in another container on the server.

Trouble is, I can't seem to connect from a web browser, to bring up the "famous" initial WordPress setup.

I've enabled inbound port 82 on my EC2 security group, to all IP addresses (e.g. 0.0.0.0).

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  wordpress:
    # Name of the container this service creates. Otherwise it's prefixed with the git repo name
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: wordpress:5.4.1-php7.2-fpm-alpine
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:82:9000" # for bypassing Nginx and testing on port 82
    expose: 
      - 9000 # Default for the Alpine image
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

volumes:
  wordpress:
    external: true
```

I know the security settings are correct, because I have other websites on ports 80 and 81, including the Docker "training/webapp:latest" image/container on "0.0.0.0:81->5000/tcp".

I have the database connection environment variables in a .env file:

```
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=wordpress.*************.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
WORDPRESS_DB_PORT=3306
WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=**********************
WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
```

I know the AWS RDS MySQL database works with the above credentials because I can connect to it with the command line MySQL program in Ubuntu on the EC2 server, and also using HeidiSQL on my desktop computer.

When I go to my browser and type in either the public DNS address (something like http://ec2-**-**-**-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:82/) or the public IP address (something like **.**.**.**:82) it just times out. I tried adding /wp-admin after both addresses, and it times out instantly.

I'm using the wordpress:5.4.1-php7.2-fpm-alpine image because after I get this proof-of-concept working, I'm going to put it behind my existing Nginx reverse-proxy web server, using a sub-domain. I'm told Nginx needs the PHP FPM image, and I've seen it in several tutorials.

I'm just shocked that nothing comes up in my browser. This should be simple, and I do way more complicated stuff all the time. I've followed several tutorials saying the same things, and it just doesn't work at all in the browser.

Very strangely, if I do the exact same thing on my local desktop computer, and then go to localhost:82, the initial WordPress setup comes up. I just can't seem to do the same thing on my AWS EC2 server.

Again, I've got a few other web apps running on that EC2 server, using Nginx and ports 80 and 81, so I know the server works, and the security settings are correct.

Comment: Try accessing on local host of the server, does that timeout?

Comment: Can also check NACL settings on your subnet and if you have any internal firewalls running on the instance.

Comment: @mokugo-devops if I "curl 127.0.0.1:82" I get "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"; whereas if I "curl 127.0.0.1:81" I get "Hello world!" for my Python training app Docker container on port 81

Comment: I changed WordPress from port 82 to 81, which I know is working because of the Python "Hello World!" training app I had working on 81, and it still doesn't work. I doubt it's a security or firewall thing at this point, but you never know. If I run "docker logs <container>" I get "[21-May-2020 22:22:35] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[21-May-2020 22:22:35] NOTICE: ready to handle connections" but that's it, even after I try curl or the browser.

Comment: @SeanMcCarthy : Did you have to import MySQL CA cert too ? My RDS instance needs a client cert for SSL. Do you know how to supply that while connecting locally from Desktop to RDS Aurora please ? I am using `wordpress:php8.0-fpm-alpine` image

Comment: Sorry @AngshumanAgarwal, that was a long time ago and I actually don't use WordPress anymore (Python/Flask/Dash now), so I can't remember...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason that particular "fpm-alpine" image wasn't working. I switched to the wordpress:latest image and it worked... What a silly solution.

Now to configure the non-FPM image with Nginx, just follow the steps in this [awesome article](https://russt.me/2017/03/running-wordpress-with-tlsssl-on-apache-and-nginx-as-reverse-proxy/), which addressed all my problems!

```
# image: wordpress:5.4.1-php7.2-fpm-alpine
image: wordpress:latest
```

[image]